# Why is there an option to overwrite free space twice nautilus

Tags: nautilus, security, delete, secure-erase

What is the benefit of overwriting free space more than once?

If you install the plugin that adds this option there are options like:
*overwrite free space -> overwrite once, overwrite 2 times (save from attackers) and overwrite 10 times (goodman method)* if I remember correctly.

Usually you overwrite the free space in order to fully prevent any evidence of any data you deleted, because the operating system just removes the file out of a database but doesn't overwrite it so you can still get it back if it's not overwritten by anything else. This takes much time but anyway: why overwrite two times?

Comment: If you are scrubbing data off a spinning disk drive, it is possible for government agencies to recover data that has been overwritten once. This is because there are magnetic "echoes" left on the platter where the desired data once sat. When you overwrite more than once, these echoes become too faint (for most agencies) to detect. If you are using an SSD, overwriting is irrelevant as the automatic TRIM will make data recovery darn near impossible, particularly if the SSD has hardware encryption enabled.

Comment: A good answer and a good comment BUT your question has noting to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Well I had to write a good answer because I might get permanently answer locked, and I thought, it's about nautilus and nautilus is the ubuntu file manger program so why not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last century, more precisely in 1996, security researcher Peter Gutmann published a study claiming that overwriting data on a magnetic disk would leave magnetization remnants of the overwritten data at the borders of the track which, given sufficient resources (say, a state actor) might allow to recover part or all of the previous content. Elaborate strategies of repeatedly overwriting with various bit patterns were designed to minimize the chances of such a recovery.

With modern magnetic storage methods and densities that problem does not exist anymore, and with SSDs it never existed. The various recommendations to overwrite deleted data more than once (such as the famous DoD 5220.22-M 3-pass standard) are therefore obsolete and have mostly been revoked. But the story persists in collective memory and as a consequence, programmers worldwide reimplement that standard to this day because "it is known" that to erase data reliably "you have to" overwrite it multiple times.

Modern storage media present very different challenges for making sure deleted data is unrecoverably erased. Bad block replacement, caching, wear leveling may all result in data persisting somewhere on the device even though it has been deleted or overwritten. Multiple overwrite passes do not help against these.

In sum, overwriting more than once does not buy you anything on a storage medium that's less than 20 years old, except perhaps on floppy disks if you still have them.